# How to exclude JQuery/Javascript fade in & out function on certain links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

I'm using this fade in and out JQuery/Javascript effect on my site to have each page fade in and out when a link is clicked. It's working great when the link that is clicked leads to a different page, but it is causing problems when the link leads to a different part of the page (such as my back to top link), when a mailto link is clicked, and when a link that is suppose to open up in a new page or tab is clicked. When these type of links are clicked they just lead to a blank white page because they don't lead to a new page. Here is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Fades body
    $("body").fadeIn(1500);

    //Applies to every link
    $("a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;
        $("body").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);      
    });

    //Redirects page
    function redirectPage() {
        window.location = linkLocation;
    }
});
```

Because of this I'm trying to figure out if there is a way where I can exclude this fade in/out function from certain links (such as the back to top link), but I don't know how to do it. I know that rather than set all the links to fade in/out I can set the fade in/out effect to a specific class that way it doesn't effect every link. However because the site is rather large, it would be extremely tedious and difficult to add that class to every link. So rather than do that I'm wondering if theres a way to define a no-fade class that would exclude this fade in/out function? That way I could apply that class to these few links that are having problems and make those links behave normally.

It seems like a simple thing to do, but because I'm still not very fluent in javascript/jquery I don't know how to do it. Any help would be much appreciated!

*EDIT: Here is the solution incase anybody else has a similar issue. Thanks to David for the missing piece!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Fades body
    $("body").fadeIn(1500);

    //Applies to every link EXCEPT .no-fade class
    $("a").not(".no-fade").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;
        $("body").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);      
    });

    //Redirects page
    function redirectPage() {
        window.location = linkLocation;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, you could indeed define a class that when applied to an anchor would exclude it from performaing your fade out and redirect.

So if you had an anchor you wanted your default fade-out behaviour to apply to then simply leave it as is.If you didn't want this behaviour then you could apply a class (we'll call it *no-fade") to the anchor.

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://mysite.com/anotherPage">Another page</a>
<a href="http://mysite.com#backToTop" class="no-fade">Back to top</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("body").fadeIn(1500);

        $("a").not(".no-fade").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            linkLocation = this.href;
            $("body").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);      
        });

        // Redirects page
        function redirectPage() {
            window.location = linkLocation;
        }
    });

</script>
```

The only thing I've edited from your code is the selection of the anchors which I changed from:

```
$("a")
```

to

```
$("a").not(".no-fade")
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the help. I tried inserting this into the script, but I don't think I'm doing it right cause it's not working. Sorry still pretty new to javascript/jquery. What would I put in the //etc area? And where should I place this in the script?

Comment: Awesome! Updated answer anyway!

Comment: Awesome! I updated the question too with the solution. Right after I replied to your original answer I realized what you did haha. Great answer, simple, to the point, and accomplished exactly what I wanted. You got the solution ;D Would up vote you, but I don't have a high enough rep yet :(

Answer (score 0):

The *unobtrusive way* would be to look for the hash symbol (`#`) or `mailto:`, etc. to prevent those types of links from fading out:

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qJrte/7/)

```
$("a").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    linkLocation = $(this).attr('href');
    if(linkLocation.indexOf('#') != -1 || linkLocation.indexOf('mailto:') != -1)
    {redirectPage();}
    else if($(this).attr('target') && $(this).attr('target').indexOf('_') != -1) window.open(linkLocation);
    else $("body").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);
});
```

Also, `linkLocation = this.href` should be `linkLocation = $(this).attr('href')`

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the help. I tried your code and it is working for the back to the top button, but how would I use this for href="mailto:" links and target="_blank" links?

Comment: Thanks again for the help Alex, but I had to go with Davids answer.

Comment: @juroto I just fixed my code. My solution is what's called [Unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) because it doesn't require adding an unnecessary CSS class to every link to achieve the end result.

Comment: I see, this also works great and is an awesome alternate solution. While it is a little bit more js code, I wouldn't have to worry about giving these type of links no-fade classes later on, which is very nice. Thanks for updating the solution and taking the time to write up the fiddle Alex!

Comment: One issue with your script that I'm having though is when it comes to the back to top button it is doing this weird glitch. I'm pretty sure it is conflicting with this other script I'm using which animates the back to top transition. Here is the code:
`// SCROLL TO TOP
$('#top').bind('click',function(){
$('html, body').animate({
scrollTop:0
}, $(window).scrollTop() / 1.5);
return false;
});`

Comment: It seems like it is jumping to the top of the container without the animation briefly and then jumping back to the bottom and executing the animation to the top like it is suppose to. Have any suggestions on to fix this glitch?